# Line is erased when drawing shapes

Tags: iphone, path, draw, shapes, cg

I am trying to make an application for drawing shapes on screen by touching it.

I can draw a line from one point to another- but it erases on each new draw.

Here is my code:

```
CGPoint location;
CGContextRef context;
CGPoint drawAtPoint;
CGPoint lastPoint;
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    //[self addSubview:noteView];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blueColor] set];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,10);
    drawAtPoint.x =location.x;
    drawAtPoint.y =location.y;
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context,CGRectMake(drawAtPoint.x, drawAtPoint.y, 2, 2));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    lastPoint.x =location.x;
    lastPoint.y =location.y;
}
```

Appreciate your help-

Nir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, -drawRect is where you display the contents of a view. You will only 'see' on screen what you draw here.

This is much more low-level than something like Flash where you might add a movieclip containing a line to the stage and some time later add another movieclip containing a line to the stage and now you see - two lines!

You will need to do some work and prdobably set up something like..

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 
    location = [touch locationInView:touch.view]; 

    [self addNewLineFrom:lastPoint to:location];

    lastPoint = location;

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)]; 
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for( Line *eachLine in lineArray )
        [eachLine drawInContext:context];

}
```

I think you can see how to flesh this out to what you need.

Another way to approach this is to use CALayers. Using this approach you dont draw inside - - (void)drawRect at all - you add and remove layers, draw what you like inside them, and the view will handle compositing them together and drawing to the screen as needed. Probably more what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you mean CALayers instead of UILayers.  He will still have to do some custom drawing in the CALayer's drawInContext: method or the delegate -drawLayer:inContext: method, but you're right that the layers will preserve their content until redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that `drawRect` is called, you start with a blank slate.  If you don't keep track of everything you have drawn before in order to draw it again, then you end up only drawing the latest swipe of your finger, and not any of the old ones.  You will have to keep track of all of your finger swipes in order to redraw them every time `drawRect` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redrawing every line, you can draw into an image and then just display the image in your `drawRect:` method. The image will accumulate the lines for you. Of course, this method makes undo more difficult to implement.

From the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/GraphicsandDrawing/GraphicsandDrawing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW14):

> Use the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
>   function to create a new image-based
>   graphics context. After creating this
>   context, you can draw your image
>   contents into it and then use the
>   UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext
>   function to generate an image based on
>   what you drew. (If desired, you can
>   even continue drawing and generate
>   additional images.) When you are done
>   creating images, use the
>   UIGraphicsEndImageContext function to
>   close the graphic context. If you
>   prefer using Core Graphics, you can
>   use the CGBitmapContextCreate function
>   to create a bitmap graphics context
>   and draw your image contents into it.
>   When you finish drawing, use the
>   CGBitmapContextCreateImage function to
>   create a CGImageRef from the bitmap
>   context. You can draw the Core
>   Graphics image directly or use this it
>   to initialize a UIImage object.